# IIS subdomain suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, iis-8, socialengine

I created a subdomain yesterday for testing purpose of its main site and copied the files from main folder to the sub folder.Everything was set up and working yesterday after completing the path and database changes.

Now when I checked in the morning, the subdomain is down. but the surprising thing is that, it is only down here(in India ) but working perfectly in UAE(where server is set).Here the website shows dns lookup error

The website is socialengine based, but when I completely moved the files to a subfolder in the root and added a plane html file(hello world), it is still not working here, but the change does took place and echoing hello world in uae.

Some people says it will be back to normal after couple of hours,but Why is it happening?What could be the reason?Has anyone encountered the same issue ?Nothing fruitfull from searching for about an hour..

Thank you guys